# How to generate Fibonacci Series

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to Generate Fibonacci series in sql !

I need to generate Fibonacci series 0 1 1 2 3  5 8 13 21 ... N

I did this easily using C-code I need to do this using Sql !

Comment: This is one crazy Homework given ! to torture students ! @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Also, StackOverflow isn't here to complete your homework for you.

Comment: Question is Off-Topic according to StackOverflow guidelines:
"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this !

```
declare @a int
declare @b int
declare @c int
Declare @i int

set @a=0
set @b=1
set @i=0
set @c=0
Print 'Fibonacci Series'
print @a
print @b
while @i<10 
Begin
set @c=@a+@b
print @c
set @i=@i+1
set @a=@b
set @b=@c
end
```

## Outputs !

```
Fibonacci Series
```

0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89

Answer (score 18):

**Try This Simple Query:**

1) For Result In Row-by-Row (Single Column, Multiple Rows)

```
WITH Fibonacci (PrevN, N) AS
(
     SELECT 0, 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT N, PrevN + N
     FROM Fibonacci
     WHERE N < 1000000000
)
SELECT PrevN as Fibo
     FROM Fibonacci
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

*Output 1:*

[image]

2) For Result in Only One Row (Comma sepreted, in Single Cell)

```
WITH Fibonacci (PrevN, N) AS
(
 SELECT 0, 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N, PrevN + N
    FROM Fibonacci
    WHERE N < 1000000000
)
SELECT Substring(
    (SELECT cast(', ' as varchar(max)) + cast(PrevN as varchar(max)
);
FROM Fibonacci
FOR XML PATH('')),3,10000000) AS list
```

*Output 2:*
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
SELECT 0  AS fib_number UNION ALL
SELECT
    FLOOR(POWER(( 1 + SQRT(5) ) / 2.0, number) / SQRT(5) + 0.5)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE TYPE = 'p' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 70
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
 Declare @Fib int = 5
 ;with cte as
 (
   Select 0 as Previous,1 as Next ,0 as Level 
   union all
   Select Next,Next + Previous,Level +1 from cte 
   where Level +1 <@Fib
 )
 Select Previous as FibonacciSeries from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for generating the first 10 numbers in the series.

```
DECLARE @NoOne INT,  @NoTwo INT
DECLARE @FibonacciTable TABLE (Number INT NOT NULL)
--Insert first two numbers 0 and 1
INSERT @FibonacciTable (Number) SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1
SELECT @NoOne = 0, @NoTwo = 1

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FibonacciTable) < 10
BEGIN
    INSERT @FibonacciTable (Number) VALUES(@NoOne + @NoTwo)
    SELECT @NoTwo = @NoOne + @NoTwo, @NoOne = @NoTwo - @NoOne
END
SELECT * FROM @FibonacciTable   
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Fibonacci (value BIGINT)
GO

INSERT INTO #Fibonacci(value) SELECT 0
INSERT INTO #Fibonacci(value) SELECT 1
SELECT * FROM #Fibonacci
GO

INSERT INTO #Fibonacci(value) 
SELECT SUM(value) FROM ( SELECT TOP 2 * FROM #Fibonacci ORDER BY value DESC ) AS value
GO 10   --  Loop insert 10 value...

SELECT * FROM #Fibonacci
DROP TABLE #Fibonacci
```

**[Result Code](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2gudpv9.jpg)**