# How to continously add values of starting row and next row to it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

i just want to create an sql query and the result is something like on the image., something like Fibonacci sequence in SQL.

Ex.

Column 1: 10 , then the value of Result column is Result: 10 , since that is the first row. , then assuming that the value of column1 2nd row is 50, then the value of Result 2nd row will be 60.. (Result: 60).. and so on.

Sample is the image below.

How can i do that continuously ? any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746100/how-to-generate-fibonacci-series

Comment: @willoller thanks for that , but actually 'im looking on how to add values between two columns "column1 and result" like on the image above, not as simple as creating a fibonacci sequence. Something like fibonacci but addition of numbers is between two columns.

Comment: Are you asking for a running total?

Comment: Search for "SQL Recursive CTE* or *Recursive SQL Common Table Expression*.

Comment: @Blorgbeard , yup something like running total. do you have any sql query for that ? so that i can study the code and apply the logic on my side. Thanks

Comment: If you google for "sql running total", you'll find some helpful links. I think the fibonacci thing was a red-herring, and may have stopped you finding anything useful.

Comment: E.g. http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: How you are ordering your data? Without order running total has no meaning.

Comment: @Blorgbeard , yup actually i am continuously finding solution on my problem.. thanks for responses, much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any id column with which you can order?

Comment: @DarkKnight actually the ordering doesn't matter to me.. but if you are asking any id to be use for looping purposes, that is the same thing i wanna do, to insert in temp table with identity and make a loop with it, but my problem is how to do the logic of adding the values between the two columns to get the running total.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal , please see my comment to DarkKnight regarding order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `MSSQL2012` or higher you can use `OVER` clause.

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.value, SUM(t2.value) OVER (ORDER BY t2.id) as [Result]
FROM   Test01 t2
ORDER BY t2.id;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8f56/4)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you so much Sabyasachi, it works! :) , i used this one since im using 2012 version.. and this makes lesser code and easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST(ID INT,VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES
(1,10),(2,20),(3,30),(4,40),(5,50),(6,60),(7,70)

;WITH CTE
as
(
   SELECT ID,VALUE,VALUE AS RESULT FROM #TEST WHERE ID=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT T.ID,T.VALUE,T.VALUE+C.RESULT
   FROM #TEST T INNER JOIN CTE C ON T.ID = C.ID+1
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much.. this is exactly the logic im looking for, but i just wanna ask a question :) since i am new to CTE , is that a built-in function in sql ? , this is the first i am going to use that :) Thanks.

Comment: CTE is not keyword or function. Try googling for 'Common Table Expression'. you will see many references. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select Id, value,
(select sum(t2.value) from TEST01 t2 where t2.id <= t1.id ) 
as Result
from TEST01 t1
```

Find the solution in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8f56/2

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a window function.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(ID INT, val INT);

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (1,10),
                            (2,7),
                            (3,-4),
                            (4,1);
SELECT ID, 
       val,
       SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY ID 
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                      AND CURRENT ROW) AS result
FROM @myTable
ORDER BY ID;

ID  val  result
--  ---  ------
1   10   10
2   7    17
3   -4   13
4   1    14
```