# SQL query to find the running total

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Kindly help me with finding the running total for the below table

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c0ec/1

The example shown above is a sample. The actual query used to arrive at this place is quite large, hence self join is not a viable option. Kindly suggest a function like sum() over(.....)

Following will be the output

[image]
thanks in advance

Comment: kindly specify the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to use subquery:

```
select *, (select sum(salary) from tablename t2 where t2.id <= t1.id) as runningsalary
from tablename t1
```

In `Sql Server 2012 +` you can use window function for this:

```
select *, sum(salary) over(order by id) as runningsalary
from tablename t1
```

Answer (score 1):

I ask that before, You can use `Common Table Expression (CTE)` in 2008 version, and `OVER` clause in 2012

Here's is one answer i get from Dark Knight.

```
    CREATE TABLE #TEST(ID INT,VALUE INT)
    INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES
    (1,10),(2,20),(3,30),(4,40),(5,50),(6,60),(7,70)

    ;WITH CTE
    as
    (
       SELECT ID,VALUE,VALUE AS RESULT FROM #TEST WHERE ID=1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT T.ID,T.VALUE,T.VALUE+C.RESULT
       FROM #TEST T INNER JOIN CTE C ON T.ID = C.ID+1
    )

    SELECT * FROM CTE
```

credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240745/5197152

[How to continously add values of starting row and next row to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240354/how-to-continously-add-values-of-starting-row-and-next-row-to-it)

Hope that thread will help you.