# Excel powerquery custom custom column self reference?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Trying to create a power query column where it adds how many consecutive days a certain row is in the top 10 and reset to 0 if it falls out.

(every time I data refresh the list changes). I try to create a custom column but I am unable to reference itself. Is that possible?

I am trying to do something in the lines of

```
if [Rank] < 11 then [Days in top 10] + 1 else 0
```

If rank is between 1-10 then add one to itself else reset to 0

[image: data example]

[image]

Comment: You can't do proper recursion with DAX as far as I can tell. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766022/recursion-in-dax

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, expected results, and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response the line above is what I have tried. basically if the rank column is between 1-10 then i want to add one to the [days in top 10] column or reset to 0.


i also added a picture of the data
and the [days in top 10] is the custom column i'm creating which I am unable to self reference or do recursion as the previous commentor said.