# DAX or POWER Query recursive calculation

Tags: dax, powerquery

Please advise if the below case may have a solution in DAX, Power query.

Have a model in Excel to identify reorder points based on Min/Max levels over 52 time periods (year). It works perfectly with 1 item, start having difficulties with 3,000 part #s (array formulas and chain calculations) therefore trying to rebuild that with DAX.   Was able to reproduce all columns in DAX except for [Reorder] and [Inbound], spits out circular dependency error. I understand that DAX was not meant to be used for recursive calculations, however, I am sure there must be a workaround.

This is an abstract of an Excel spreadsheet (1 with part #)
[image: This is an abstract of an Excel spreadsheet (1 with part #)]

where:

```
Safety, Min & Max  - stock levels

LT Weeks - lead time (time between ordering and restocking)

INV_0 - opening inventory = Closing inventory from the previous period

INV_1 - closing inventory

Demand - outbound quantity = separately modeled forecast 

Inbound - inbound = Quantity reordered [LT Weeks] periods ago

Reorder - reorder quantity =
IF (
    [INV_1] - [DEMAND] + [INBOUND] + [PIPELINE] <= MIN,
    [MAX] - ( [INV_0] - [DEMAND] + [INBOUND] + [PIPELINE] ),
    0
)

Pipeline - sum of quantities reordered in preceding [LT weeks] interval -1

Total inv  = INV_1 + [Pipeline].
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766022/recursion-in-dax