# DAX - formula referencing itself

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggling to recreate the following Excel logic in DAX:

[image]

`Cont` and `CF` are both data columns (sourced from SQL database), while `A` value is dynamic as it comes from What-if analysis:

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, `A` measure doesn't properly calculate the values for year > 2021. I simply fail to understand how the formula can reference "itself" (i.e. previous row's result). I tried to play with `EARLIER` function but it doesn't seem to work with measures. I also tried to create a calculated column instead of a measure, but these fail to cooperate with what-if parameters.

Here's what I have so far:

```
mA = 
    var Cont = SELECTEDVALUE(JP[Cont])
    var CF = SELECTEDVALUE(JP[CF])
    var AR =  1.03
return
    A[Parameter Value] * AR - CF + Cont
```

Any tips & solutions would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot recursively self-reference a column in DAX.

See this related question: [Recursion in DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766022/recursion-in-dax)

However, for this particular case, you can create a closed-form formula for the column you want by realizing that for year N, the result you want can be written as

```
A * AR^N + sum_(i=1)^N AR^(N-i) (Cont_i - CF_i)
```

In DAX this can be written as follows (where `Yr = N` and `JP[Year] = i`):

```
mA = 
VAR AR = 1.03
VAR Yr =  SELECTEDVALUE ( JP[Year] )
VAR Temp =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( ALL ( JP ), JP[Year] <= Yr ),
        "Const", ( JP[Cont] - JP[CF] ) * POWER ( AR, Yr - JP[Year] )
    )
RETURN
    A[Parameter Value] * POWER ( AR, Yr ) + SUMX ( Temp, [Const] )
```

If you're starting with 2021, then you'll need to subtract 2020 from the `Yr` variable.

[image: Result]

Comment: Alexis, you probably heard it numerous times already, but you Sir are a genius! Works beautifully, I cannot thank you enough :-)