# Sum of previous rows of the same column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm struggling to find a way to create a column in Powerbi that is calculated with the previous row of same column. I've seen  similar questions in this forum (namely, [How to perform sum of previous cells of same column in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257536/how-to-perform-sum-of-previous-cells-of-same-column-in-powerbi) and [DAX - formula referencing itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641059/dax-formula-referencing-itself)) and I tried to adapt the  indicated solutions to my case but without sucess.

Is it possible to create a calculated column with DAX that replicates what i'm doing in excel? or is it one of those cases that is not possible to create a closed-form formula?

[excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8LNm.png)

Many thanks,
Paul

Comment: Do you really need a column?  maybe you can use measure for example:
measure1 =
CALCULATE(sum(TableRol[val]), FILTER(all(TableRol[Date]),  SELECTEDVALUE(TableRol[Date]) >= TableRol[Date] ))

Comment: I can also use a measure. no problem with that. the problem is that I need to calculate the max(Table[value]+Table[output],0) of the previous row as descrived in example. with your sugestion i'll get the accumulated value. Any other sugestion? Thank you!

Comment: i try every trick that i know, but without success. 

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/

Comment: Same here. it looks like that this kind of calculation simply isn't possible. thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

The example from @msta42a worked to accumulate all the values.
I modified to add a TOPN filter, that will sum only the last 7 rows.

```
measure1 =
CALCULATE(
SUM(
    Recovery[recovery_calculated]),
    TOPN(
        7,
        FILTER(
            all(Recovery[Date]), 
            SELECTEDVALUE(Recovery[Date]) >= Recovery[Date] 
        ),
        Recovery[Date],
        DESC
    )
```

)