# Power BI - Reference the previous row of the current creating measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible to reference the previous row of the column I am currently creating? Not in calculate column but in measure?

[image]

For example, in Excel with can do like this in the above image.

```
Q4 = If(N3> 0,  N3 + O4 + P4, Q3 + O4 + P4) 

Q5 = If(N4> 0,  N4 + O5 + P5, Q4 + O5 + P5) and so on.
```

But I couldn't find a way to do so in Power BI...

I have created a visual table below in Power BI, and now need to add the new measure like column Q in Excel in my visual table.

[image]

I saw many posts and videos are using Earlier in the calculated column, but I would need to create this with a measure.

I have been trying this for many hours, it would be great if someone has solutions.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, you cannot [recursively self-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766022/recursion-in-dax) the same column that you are trying to define.

This looks like it might be convertible to a closed-form formula where before May 2020 you calculate using `Inventory`, `Inbound`, and `Outbound` as expected and after May 2020 you take the inventory from April 2020 plus the cumulative sum of `Inbound` and `Outbound` from April to whatever month you're on. Ugly to write but seems possible.