# PowerBI Opening/closing circular dependency

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a logic in PowerBI to use T-1 closing balance as my T opening balance. But I'm getting "Circular dependency" error. Table looks like:

```
Date   Opening  CurrentDay Closing
Jan 1     0         100      100
Jan 2     100      -200     -100
Jan 3    -100       200      100
Jan 4     100      -100      0
Jan 5     0         300      300
```

Date and CurrentDay balance is in my data table;
Opening/closing are calculated columns or measures. Opening = previous closing; Closing = opening+currentday.

Any suggestion?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You [can't write recursive formulas in DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766022/recursion-in-dax).

The way you would do this is to write `Opening` and `Closing` as [running totals](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/computing-running-totals-in-dax/) of `CurrentDay` where `Opening` is the total *up to* the current day and `Closing` is the total *including* the current day.